# Sort Swagger Tags

Tags: python, swagger, flasgger

Hi I'm using flasgger/swagger but I was wondering if there are feature where in I could sort all my tags in alphabetical order? right I don't understand the order of my tags. It's neither Alpha nor Numeric. Sample order is like this

```
User
   - API GET
   - API POST
   - API PUT
   - API DELETE
Company
   - API GET
   - API POST
   - API PUT
   - API DELETE
Room
   - API GET
   - API POST
   - API PUT
   - API DELETE
```

So basically User, Company and Rooms are Swagger Tags. I would like to arrange it where in **Company** should come first then followed by **Room** then **User**. Is there a way to achieve this in swagger 2.0

Updates:
I would like it to be sorted in web browser display. In short on how we see the presentation of all this Tags in sorted order

Comment: Do you mean sorting in Swagger UI?

Comment: @Helen Yes... The way it's presented on the browser

Comment: What you're asking is an implementation detail. If you're using `flasgger`, it builds ups the `tags` list in the order of method definition. So you should look at registering views to your routes in a lexicographical order. Or better

Answer (score 0):

For everyone who have problem with tag order, you can do it with javascript (sample is sorting alphabetically ascending, but you can change sort function as you wish):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    sort();
});

function sort() {
    ascending = true;
    var tbody = document.getElementById("resources");//ul
    var rows = tbody.childNodes;//li
    var unsorted = true;

    while (unsorted) {
        unsorted = false

        for (var r = 0; r < rows.length - 1; r++) {
            debugger;
            var row = rows[r];
            var nextRow = rows[r + 1];

            var value = row.getAttribute("id");
            var nextValue = nextRow.getAttribute("id");

            if (ascending ? value > nextValue : value < nextValue) {
                tbody.insertBefore(nextRow, row);
                unsorted = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This JS you should register as it is shown in example bellow (Web api / c# / .net)

```
config.EnableSwagger(c =>
            {
                ***
            })
            .EnableSwaggerUi(u =>  
                {                   
                    u.InjectJavaScript(typeof(Startup).Assembly, "yourNamespace.SwaggerExt.js");
                }
            );
```

JS file should be embedded resource.